# Create generic array as static field

Tags: java, annotations

This doesn't compile:

```
  public static Class<? extends Annotation>[] annots = {
    NotNull.class,
    ColumnType.class,
    RuntimeType.class,
    DefaultValue.class
  };
```

I get this error:

> Generic array creation

Note that the above classes are Annotations declared like so:

```
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface NotNull {
    boolean value() default false;
  }

  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface ColumnType {
    Class<?> value();
  }
```

does anyone know how I can create a generic array?

Comment: [You can't.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a List instead

```
public static List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annots = Arrays.asList(
          NotNull.class,
          RuntimeType.class,
          DefaultValue.class);
  };
```

Comment: It's a `static` - make it `final`! Also `Collections.unmodifiableList`. Also, from Java SE 9, just use `List.of`.

Answer (score 0):

You create like below:

```
     public static Class<? extends Annotation>[] annots = new Class[] {
        NotNull.class,
        ColumnType.class,
        RuntimeType.class,
        DefaultValue.class
     };
```

However, it will give you a warning.

> Type safety: The expression of type Class[] needs unchecked conversion
>   to conform to Class[]

Comment: The compiler is required by the language to give a warning because it really is unsafe. You could assign a non-annotation as an element of the array.